# Random Typing error with TypeScript that disappears

Tags: typescript

I have a random error whilst upgrading a project from Typescript 4.9.3 to 5.1.3

This isn't an IDE issue that I can think of as it happens in both VS Code and Webstorm.

I have TSC v 5.1.3 installed on my Mac, project has been fully updated to TS 5.1.3 and the last weird error is this.

Here's the code:

```
const ShortCodeSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  code: Yup.string()
    .min(3)
    .matches(/^((?!\/).)*$/),
  languageId: Yup.string().optional(),
});

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  title: Yup.string().required("admin.snippets.drawer.validation.name"),
  shortCodes: Yup.array(ShortCodeSchema).test(
    "shortcodes",
    "admin.snippets.drawer.validation.no_deplicate_shortcode",
    (shortCodes) => {
      const counts = shortCodes?.reduce((acc, shortCode) => {
        if (shortCode?.code && acc.has(shortCode.code)) {
          acc.set(shortCode.code, acc.get(shortCode.code)! + 1);
        } else if (shortCode?.code) {
          acc.set(shortCode.code, 1); 
        }
        return acc;
      }, new Map<string, number>());

      const hasDuplicates =
        typeof [...(counts ?? []).values()].find((count) => count > 1) === "number";

      return !hasDuplicates;
    }
  ),
});
```

And here's the error:
[TypeScript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSOMq.png)

But the weird thing is, if i click into the file and press `<space>` or anything anywhere, the error inside the IDE goes away (both VSCode and WebStorm) but TSC check on command line still reports an issue.

[TypeScript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJNCW.png)

Just wondering if i'm missing something completely here...

I've refactored this bit of code multiple times in different ways and TSC check still reports an error...

Comment: if in doubt, trust the `tsc` commandline over the IDE....

Comment: I do trust tsc CLI over IDE, but my issue is, how do i fix it lol....